New-WebServiceProxy Cmdlet does not exist
Firstly apologies for the stupid question folks, feel like I should be able to google or handle this one myself yet I'm not finding much to help.
Having an issue with the new-webserviceproxy command. I have the management module loaded and retrieving commands within shows the below (trimmed to just new- commands).
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          New-Item                                           7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          New-ItemProperty                                   7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          New-PSDrive                                        7.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          New-Service                                        7.0.0.0
New-WebServiceProxy does not seem to exist on version 7.0 of the module? I am at a loss here, i am loading two versions of the module (3.1 and 7.0)
ModuleType Version               PreRelease Name
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Manifest   3.1.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Not sure if this is the issue, attempting to remove and reinstall the modules have been a frustration. However when pulling commands it seems to be pulling from 7.0.

New-WebServiceProxy depends on a bunch of .NET Framework-specific APIs (notably client code in the System.Web.Services.Discovery namespace), that aren't available in newer versions of .NET - hence its absence from PowerShell 7.

Thanks Mathias, after doing some research it looks like I'll want to use an invoke-webrequest instead. Apologies for the foolish question :).

New-WebServiceProxy depends on a bunch of .NET Framework-specific APIs (notably client code in the System.Web.Services.Discovery namespace), that aren't available in newer versions of .NET - hence its absence from PowerShell 7. –
Mathias R. Jessen
(I have found the invoke-webrequest cmdlet should be used {in my case atleast} in replacement for the now defunct new-webserviceproxy.)
